# How to validate a text entered in spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner, luhn

In my application i have created a separate class for credit card validation.I have called credit card validation class as a method in main activity and in my main activity i have listed the card names in spinner list. For card number validation i have used LUHN algorithm and is working fine. Problem is that if i select master card from spinner and if i enter visa card number in edit text and after execution it displays valid visa card.But its wrong because in spinner list it shows master card.How to validate spinner? Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customise the TextView inside a Spinner?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714880/how-to-customise-the-textview-inside-a-spinner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemSelectedListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener%29) to register a callback when a spinner item is selected. And then override [onItemSelected()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) to retrieve the item that was selected.